Show that $\left\lvert e^{ix}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}\right\rvert\leq\min\left \{\frac {2|x|^n}{n!},\frac {|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right\}.$

Show that $$\left \lvert e^{ix} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac {(ix)^k} {k!} \right \rvert \leq \min \left \{\frac {2 \left \lvert x \right \rvert^{n}} {n!}, \frac {\left \lvert x \right \rvert^{n + 1}} {(n + 1)!} \right \}$$ for any $x \in \mathbb R.$

By separating out the real and imaginary parts of the expression in LHS and applying Taylor's theorem with remainders I am able to show that $$\left \lvert e^{ix} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac {(ix)^k} {k!} \right \rvert \leq \min \left \{\frac {\sqrt {2}\ \left \lvert x \right \rvert^{n}} {n!}, \frac {\sqrt {2}\ \left \lvert x \right \rvert^{n + 1}} {(n + 1)!} \right \}$$ for any $x \in \mathbb R.$ This is very close to the inequality I wished to prove but not quite.

The second argument of the $\min$ is the absolute value of the first term in the series that you want to bound. So you can look for cancellations between all other elements of that series.

@popoolmica$:$ Could you please explain a bit more? I am thinking about Taylor's theorem with remainders. But I am not sure whether it has a version in complex analysis. There do exist Taylor's expansions of holomorphic functions and $z \mapsto e^{iz}$ is indeed entire. But for Taylor's expansion with remainder terms we need Rolle's theorem and I don't know whether there is a version of Rolle's theorem for complex valued differentiable functions on $\mathbb R$; although we can still have the access of Rolle's theorem for real and imaginary parts of such functions.

@popoolmica$:$ I think we should break $e^{ix}$ into it's real and imaginary parts and then do the estimation separately.

@popoolmica$:$ By separating out the real and imaginary parts and applying Taylor's theorem with remainders I am able to show that $$\left \lvert e^{ix} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac {(ix)^k} {k!} \right \rvert \leq \min \left {\frac {\sqrt {2}\ \left \lvert x \right \rvert^{n}} {n!}, \frac {\sqrt {2}\ \left \lvert x \right \rvert^{n + 1}} {(n + 1)!} \right }$$ for any $x \in \mathbb R.$

This is lemma 1.2 in the appendix of Gut's Probability.

@PNDas$:$ Thanks a lot. Although for expectation inequalities my inequality is also fine, I guess.
